# Database connection error of " signup() takes no arguments 4 given"

Tags: python

Help me find where am going wrong here please....can't send anything to the database am getting this error "signup() takes no argument 4 given"

This is my model.py file

```
app.secret_key = '9vY%N\\#l\xd1L\xd6r\xac\xec\xf5\xa6\x01W9_QD\\$'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] =    'postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost/cynthia'
```

#creating tables

```
class signup(db.Model):

    __tablename__= 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String,nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String,nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String,nullable=False)
    confirm = db.Column(db.String,nullable=False)


def __init__(self, username, email, password, confirm):
    self.username= username
    self.email = email
    self.password= bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password)
    self.confirm= bcrypt.generate_password_hash(confirm)


def __repr__(self):
    return '<signup %r>' % self.username
```

my view.py is this

```
@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():    
  if request.method == "POST":
    user = signup(name= request.form['name'],
    email= request.form['email'],
    password = request.form['password'],
    confirm = request.form['confirm'])
   db.session.add(user)
   db.session.commit()
   flash("You've successfully registered")
return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

return render_template("signup.html")

Answer (score 0):

This isn't in any way at all a database connection error. It appears to be an indentation error; your `__init__` method (and the `__repr__` as well) are not inside the class, so the instantiation is not expecting the arguments you are passing.

Comment: OP also has `signup` both as a class and as a function.. this can only lead to bad things..

Comment: Ah well spotted, in fact that is even more likely to be the cause of the error.

Comment: for the indentation i think copying the code here might appear that way because of editing but am getting the error .....deep may be that might be the error lemme check....Thanks guys

Comment: def __repr__(self):
 return '<username %r>' % self.username   and still error is the same...

Comment: I have no idea what the relevance is of that comment. As DeepSpace points out, you have named your db class the same as the view function; when you call `signup()` you are now calling the function, not the class.

Comment: ooh i get it now :-)